# Shanghai,4 April 1961,B6-2-392,pp.20 ff

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does "pp.20 ff." stand for? "Page 20?????"

12 Deng Xiaoping speech on 11 Dec.1961,Hunan,141-2-138,p.43.
13 Speech on 25 March 1959,Gansu,19-18-494,p.48.
14 **Shanghai,4 April 1961,B6-2-392,pp.20 ff.**
15 Shanghai,8 July 1958,B29-2-97,p.17.

> Source: Mao's Great Famine by Frank Dikotter

Answer (score 6):

ff is an abbreviation written after the number of a page meaning ‘and the following pages’

[ff abbreviation (Oxford Learner's Dictionaries)](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/ff_2#:%7E:text=Advanced%20Learner%27s%20Dictionary-,ff.,the%20following%20pages%20or%20lines%27)

Comment: And **pp.** meaning "pages" is the plural of **p.** meaning "page"

Comment: If the quote were on a single page, you'd see "p. 20", if it were spread over 2 specific pages you'd see "pp. 20-21".  Because it starts on page 20, spans multiple pages, and the person citing it didn't bother finding a specific ending point, it's listed as "pp. 20 ff" for "pages 20 and following".

Comment: "f" is short for the Latin "folio" (meaning leaf, or sheet of paper) and "ff" means "foliis" as an indication of the plural